# DNS not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, dns

Some time ago I started having DNS problems that last good couple of months already. Randomly, during the day my web  browser stops working and I start getting "DNS probe finished no internet" errors. Sometimes it fixes itself on its own after a couple of minutes, but sometimes I need to restart my PC in order to fix this. These are the steps I took to debug the issue:

- happens with multiple web browsers and applications
- tried restarting the router
- tried switching from Ethernet (built into motherboard) to WiFi (PCI-E Wifi card) - happens on both
- tried hardcoding DNS addresses to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
- tried turning off IPv6
- tried on different PC - never have any problems with that same Wifi/router
- tried reinstalling Windows
- tried the following commands to clear DNS cache:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
netsh winsock reset
```

I tried to debug using cmd line with the following results:

```
PS > ping google.com
Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again.
PS > nslookup google.com
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  8.8.8.8

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
PS > ping 8.8.8.8

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=120
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=120
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=120
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=120

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 10ms, Maximum = 13ms, Average = 10ms
PS > ping 8.8.4.4

Pinging 8.8.4.4 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.4.4: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=120
Reply from 8.8.4.4: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=120
Reply from 8.8.4.4: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=120
Reply from 8.8.4.4: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=120

Ping statistics for 8.8.4.4:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 9ms, Maximum = 11ms, Average = 10ms
PS > ping 172.217.20.14

Pinging 172.217.20.14 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.217.20.14: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=119
Reply from 172.217.20.14: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=119
Reply from 172.217.20.14: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=119
Reply from 172.217.20.14: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=119

Ping statistics for 172.217.20.14:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 22ms, Maximum = 23ms, Average = 22ms
PS > ping google.com
Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

As you can see, DNS server is reachable, but it's not working with nslookup. Also, pinging one of Google's servers by IP address works, so it's not a problem with network connectivity.

I don't have any more ideas. Is that a hardware problem? What else would you try?

Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.19045 Build 19045

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: You've performed good tests and investigated the issue well, isolating it to one PC, and that PC **can** ping the DNS server, but cannot get DNS resolution. Two other things you might try: 1. Perform a thorough check for malware with another tool than your using, e.g., https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/free-bootable-antivirus-malware-disks/. -- something might be trying to hijack DNS lookup.  2. Try a different DNS server, e.g., Cloudflare, 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1, and 2606:4700:4700::1111 and 2606:4700:4700::1001 for iIPv6 -- see https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/setup/windows/.

Comment: tried reinstalling Windows .... In addition to the other comments, try updating the firmware on your router. You have done most other things including reinstalling Windows.

Comment: I've had the same chronic problem in my Windows 10 installation. All too often, DNS queries just vanish into the void. I suspect the local router was giving priority to other local network traffic, and dropping the DNS request packets, and the software on my machine that was issuing them just shrugged and errored out instead of persisting with the requests until one went through. I finally got into the router admin page and set bandwidth limits for all connected devices, and the problem seems to have stopped - it's been a few months now.